# Is it possible to assign different roles to different apps for the same itunesconnect user?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

thank you in advance. I'm new to iOS development and is struggling with something which should be an non-issue.

When I assign a role to an itunes connect user, that user immediately has the same permissions to all the apps inside "My Apps". I am unable to find a way to limit that user to have access to some of the apps only. Is there a way to do that?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Apple has introduced some new roles and permissions to the new iTunes connect. Using the new **App Siloing** feature of iTunes connect, you can easily achieve this.

Please check this [What is new in iTunes Connect](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-302/) WWDC 2015 session (Time from 32:00) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, that is very good news!  By the way this new feature is not out yet, right?

Comment: Answering my own question, WWDC said the new stuffs will be available "later this fall", so that means anytime now...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot limit the number of apps a iTunes connect user can see. Apple has grouped the access according to different sections. Not app based.

These roles get access for My App section : Legal (Agent), Admin,Finance, Technical

These roles don't get access for My App section : Sales, Marketing

Refer iTunes connect role at : https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/